# How to Hide few post from the Wordpress home page?

Tags: wordpress, post

I am creating a [Lyrics website](http://www.numock.com) with 3.9.1 wordpress version and I want to create a post for each Album and its songs with internal links.

What am doing right now is creating a post of albums and pages for songs. But if I do that, I am not able to give tags for pages ( songs ) for SEO.

So I want to create even songs with postings so that I can add tags to them but I don't want songs to be listed on my home page unless the visitor clicks on the link in the album.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

### Tags to Pages

If you want to add Tags for Pages you can by doing this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'tags_for_pages' );

function tags_for_pages() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'page' );
}
```

---

### Just Posts

But if you wanna do all the things just with posts, I think you should:

1) Create 2 Categories: Albums and Songs
2) Create The Albums Post and Add the Album Category to it
3) Create the Songs Post and Add the Song Category to it
4) Add this code to your functions.php

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_home_query' );

function modify_home_query( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'category_name', 'albums' );
    }
}
```

and in your home page will be only posts with the category albums, you will have to paste the links in the content of the Album Post, like you would if it was a page.

---

### Best Choice

But I think you should search for Custom Post Types, and how to create it.
You could create a **Custom Post Type** **Albums** and a Custom Post Type **Songs** and link them using plugins like [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/), [Posts 2 Posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/) and / or [CPT-Onomies](http://wordpress.org/plugins/cpt-onomies/)

Post Type Generator: http://generatewp.com/post-type/

Answer (score 0):

You can make your homepage query only look for albums. 
For this to work, you need to set posts categories "Album" or "Song".

Then, you need to find your theme home page php file, like a index.php, and look for your current query. It looks like this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
//some code
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then add this before

```
<?php query_posts('cat_name=album'); ?>
```

and this after

```
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

This will only work if you use categories!!

Comment: `<?php query_posts('cat_name=album'); ?>` -1. Use `WP_Query`